# Create a conditional if/else statement to show final Quiz score results

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not that familiar with Java. However I am trying to create an online quiz using javascript where the quiz results are displayed as a percentage using a conditional if/else statement. If test score is 70% or higher, click here. Else if test score is lower than 70%, click here to repeat test. This is what I have so far with obviously no results:

```js
var quiztitle = "Quiz";


 var quiz = [
        {
            "question" : "Q1: What colour is the sky?",
            "choices" : [
                                    "Blue",
                                    "Red",
                                    "Pink",
                                    "Green"
                                ],
            "correct" : "Blue",
            
        },
        {
            "question" : "Q2: What colour is mustard?",
            "choices" : [
                                    "Blue",
                                    "Yellow",
                                    "Green",
                                    "Red"
                                ],
            "correct" : "Yellow",
        },
        {
            "question" : "Q3: What colour is grass?",
            "choices" : [
                                    "Blue",
                                    "Yellow",
                                    "Red",
                                    "Green"
                                ],
            "correct" : "Green",
        },
     

    ];


 var currentquestion = 0,
     score = 0,
     submt = true,
     picked;

 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


     function htmlEncode(value) {
         return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
     }


     function addChoices(choices) {
         if (typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array") {
             $('#choice-block').empty();
             for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
                 $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');
             }
         }
     }

      function nextQuestion() {
         submt = true;
         $('#submitbutton').css('display','none');
   $('#form1').css('display','none');
         $('#explanation').empty();
         $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
         $('#pager').text('Question ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
         addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
         setupButtons();


     }


     function processQuestion(choice) {
         if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
             $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
     $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#6C0',
     'color': '#ffffff',
     'font-weight': '300',
       'font-size': '20px',
     'padding' : '20px'
             });
    });
             $('#explanation').fadeIn(700, function() {
      $('#explanation').html('<div class="correct"><i class="fal fa-check" style="font-family:FontAwesome; padding:30px 10px 30px 0;"></i> Correct!</div> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
      });
             score++;
         } else {
             $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
                 'background-color': '#ff0000',
     'color': '#ffffff',
     'font-weight': '300',
       'font-size': '20px',
     'padding' : '20px'
             });
             $('#explanation').fadeIn(700, function() {
     $('#explanation').html('<div class="wrong"><i class="fal fa-times" style="font-family:FontAwesome; padding:30px 10px 30px 0;"></i> Incorrect.</div> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
    });
         }
         currentquestion++;
         $('#submitbutton').fadeIn(700, function() {
    $('#submitbutton').html('NEXT QUESTION').on('click', function () {
             if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
                 endQuiz();
             } else {
                 $(this).text('NEXT QUESTION').css({
                 
                 }).off('click');
                 nextQuestion();
             }
         });
         $('#submitbutton').show();
   });
     }


     function setupButtons() {
         $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
    $('.choice').on('mouseover', function () {
             $(this).css({
                 'background-color': '#f1cb00',
     'color': '#005596',
     'font-weight': '300',
       'font-size': '20px',
     'padding' : '20px'
             });
    });
         });
         $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
    $('.choice').on('mouseout', function () {
             $(this).css({
                 'background-color': '#e1e1e1',
     'color': '#005596',
     'font-weight': '300',
       'font-size': '20px',
     'padding' : '20px'
              });
     });
         })
         $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
    $('.choice').on('click', function () {
             if (submt) {
                 submt = false;
                 picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
                 $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
                 $(this).css({
                 
                 });
                 $('.choice').css({
                     'cursor': 'default'
                 });
                 
                 processQuestion(picked);
                 $('#submitbutton').css({
     'padding' : '20px'
                 });
     
             }
     });
         })
     }


     function endQuiz() {
         $('#explanation').empty();
         $('#question').empty();
   $('.pager').hide();
         $('#choice-block').empty();
         $('#submitbutton').remove();
         $(document.createElement('h2')).css({
    'line-height' : '20px',
    'text-align' : 'center'
         }).text(Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100) + '%').insertAfter('#question');
   
   
   $('#form1').show();
     }
  



     function init() {
         //add title
         if (typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string") {
             $(document.createElement('header')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
         } else {
             $(document.createElement('header')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
         }

         //add pager and questions
         if (typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array") {
             //add pager
             $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id', 'pager').text('Question 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
             //add first question
             $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');
             
             $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id', 'explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

             //questions holder
             $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame').css({
    'padding-top' : '20px'
              })//add choices
             addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);
             
             //add submit button
             $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('NEXT QUESTION').css({
                 
             }).appendTo('#frame');

             setupButtons();
             $('#submitbutton').hide();
    $('#form1').hide();
         }
     }

     init();
 });
```

```css
 
  header {
 background: #005596;
 color:#ffffff;
 padding:20px;
 overflow:auto;
 font-size:21pt;
 margin-bottom:40px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
 }
 
.correct {
 color:#6C0; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight:500; font-size: 26pt; text-align:left; padding:30px 0 10px 30px;
}

.wrong {
 color:#ff0000; font-family:Tahoma, sans-serif; font-weight:500; font-size: 26pt; text-align:left; padding:30px 0 10px 30px;
 }
 
  ol, ul {
      list-style:none;
   list-style-position:inside;
   
  }
  
  
  
  
  p.pager {
      margin:5px 0 5px;
      font-weight:500;
   font-size:2em;
   line-height:2em;
      color:#999;
  }
  
  
  #choice-block {
      display:block;
      list-style:none;
      margin:-20px 15px 0 -15px;
      padding:0;
  }
  
  #submitbutton {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
  border:none;
  appearance:none;
  background:#005596;
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 12px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:20px;
  }
  #submitbutton:hover {
   background-color:#f1cb00;
  text-decoration:none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
   #Submit {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
  border:none;
  appearance:none;
  background:#005596;
 display:inline-block;
 text-decoration:none;
 padding: 20px;
  font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-top:20px;
  }
  #Submit:hover {
   background-color:#f1cb00;
  text-decoration:none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.3s;
  transition: 0.3s;
  }
  
  
  .choice-box {
      display:block;
      text-align:left;
      margin:8px auto;
      color: #005596;
   font-weight: 300;
     font-size: 20px;
   padding: 20px;
      cursor:pointer;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
   background:#e1e1e1;
  }
  
 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { 
 .correct {
 padding:20px 0 0 0;
}

.wrong {
 padding:20px 0 0 0;
 }

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "frame" role = "content" >
```

Comment: "with obviously no results" -- you haven't given enough of a [mcve] for anything to be "obvious". What is `score`? How did you give it a value?

Comment: Sorry I did not include the entire script:

Comment: I've added the full code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the code. Perhaps this is what you need, **but** this is not the best implementation of this app.

This is a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and of course, you can use jQuery for that, but there are much better solutions. The best way is to use one of frameworks (e.g. Angular, Vue.js, React and so on). I strongly advise you to get more info about the frameworks and start to use them.

In my opinion Vue.js has a low entry threshold and I advice to read [the doc](https://vuejs.org/), but each framework have own advantages.

Some links:

- [Vue.js: Comparison with Other Frameworks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/comparison.html)
- [Create a quiz with Vue.js](https://codeburst.io/create-a-quiz-with-vue-js-ed1e8e0e8294)
- [Angular Quiz Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kmturley/3k34hnjk/)
- [Build An Angular Quiz App From Scratch](https://hungryturtlecode.com/projects/1-build-angular-quiz-app-scratch/)

```js
var quiztitle = "Quiz";


var quiz = [{
    "question": "Q1: What colour is the sky?",
    "choices": [
      "Blue",
      "Red",
      "Pink",
      "Green"
    ],
    "correct": "Blue",

  },
  {
    "question": "Q2: What colour is mustard?",
    "choices": [
      "Blue",
      "Yellow",
      "Green",
      "Red"
    ],
    "correct": "Yellow",
  },
  {
    "question": "Q3: What colour is grass?",
    "choices": [
      "Blue",
      "Yellow",
      "Red",
      "Green"
    ],
    "correct": "Green",
  },


];


var currentquestion = 0,
  score = 0,
  submt = true,
  picked;

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


  function htmlEncode(value) {
    return $(document.createElement('div')).text(value).html();
  }


  function addChoices(choices) {
    if (typeof choices !== "undefined" && $.type(choices) == "array") {
      $('#choice-block').empty();
      for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        $(document.createElement('li')).addClass('choice choice-box').attr('data-index', i).text(choices[i]).appendTo('#choice-block');
      }
    }
  }

  function nextQuestion() {
    submt = true;
    $('#submitbutton').css('display', 'none');
    $('#form1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#explanation').empty();
    $('#question').text(quiz[currentquestion]['question']);
    $('#pager').text('Question ' + Number(currentquestion + 1) + ' of ' + quiz.length);
    addChoices(quiz[currentquestion]['choices']);
    setupButtons();


  }


  function processQuestion(choice) {
    if (quiz[currentquestion]['choices'][choice] == quiz[currentquestion]['correct']) {
      $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
        $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
          'background-color': '#6C0',
          'color': '#ffffff',
          'font-weight': '300',
          'font-size': '20px',
          'padding': '20px'
        });
      });
      $('#explanation').fadeIn(700, function() {
        $('#explanation').html('<div class="correct"><i class="fal fa-check" style="font-family:FontAwesome; padding:30px 10px 30px 0;"></i> Correct!</div> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
      });
      score++;
    } else {
      $('.choice').eq(choice).css({
        'background-color': '#ff0000',
        'color': '#ffffff',
        'font-weight': '300',
        'font-size': '20px',
        'padding': '20px'
      });
      $('#explanation').fadeIn(700, function() {
        $('#explanation').html('<div class="wrong"><i class="fal fa-times" style="font-family:FontAwesome; padding:30px 10px 30px 0;"></i> Incorrect.</div> ' + htmlEncode(quiz[currentquestion]['explanation']));
      });
    }
    currentquestion++;
    $('#submitbutton').fadeIn(700, function() {
      $('#submitbutton').html('NEXT QUESTION').on('click', function() {
        if (currentquestion == quiz.length) {
          endQuiz();
        } else {
          $(this).text('NEXT QUESTION').css({

          }).off('click');
          nextQuestion();
        }
      });
      $('#submitbutton').show();
    });
  }


  function setupButtons() {
    $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
      $('.choice').on('mouseover', function() {
        $(this).css({
          'background-color': '#f1cb00',
          'color': '#005596',
          'font-weight': '300',
          'font-size': '20px',
          'padding': '20px'
        });
      });
    });
    $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
      $('.choice').on('mouseout', function() {
        $(this).css({
          'background-color': '#e1e1e1',
          'color': '#005596',
          'font-weight': '300',
          'font-size': '20px',
          'padding': '20px'
        });
      });
    })
    $('.choice').fadeIn(700, function() {
      $('.choice').on('click', function() {
        if (submt) {
          submt = false;
          picked = $(this).attr('data-index');
          $('.choice').removeAttr('style').off('mouseout mouseover');
          $(this).css({

          });
          $('.choice').css({
            'cursor': 'default'
          });

          processQuestion(picked);
          $('#submitbutton').css({
            'padding': '20px'
          });

        }
      });
    })
  }


  function endQuiz() {
    $('#explanation').empty();
    $('#question').empty();
    $('.pager').hide();
    $('#choice-block').empty();
    $('#submitbutton').remove();

    /**
    * Added by Max
    */
        const percents = Math.round(score / quiz.length * 100);

        let $link = $(document.createElement('a'))
        .css({
        'line-height': '20px',
        'text-align': 'center'
      });
    const $percents = $(document.createElement('h2'))
      .css({
        'line-height': '20px',
        'text-align': 'center'
      })
      .text(percents + '%');

        if (percents >= 70) {
      $link.text('Click here');
      $link.attr('href', 'https://google.com');
    } else {
      $link.text('Click here to repeat test');
      $link.attr('href', '#0')
      $link.on('click', ($event) => {
        $event.preventDefault();
        
            clearContent();
        init();
      });
    }  

        $('#question').append($percents);
    $('#question').append($link);
    
    /**
    * End Added by Max
    */

    $('#form1').show();
  }

  // Added by Max
    function clearContent () {
    currentquestion = 0;
    score = 0;
    submt = true;
    picked = undefined;

    $('#frame').empty();
  }


  function init() {
    //add title
    if (typeof quiztitle !== "undefined" && $.type(quiztitle) === "string") {
      $(document.createElement('header')).text(quiztitle).appendTo('#frame');
    } else {
      $(document.createElement('header')).text("Quiz").appendTo('#frame');
    }

    //add pager and questions
    if (typeof quiz !== "undefined" && $.type(quiz) === "array") {
      //add pager
      $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('pager').attr('id', 'pager').text('Question 1 of ' + quiz.length).appendTo('#frame');
      //add first question
      $(document.createElement('h2')).addClass('question').attr('id', 'question').text(quiz[0]['question']).appendTo('#frame');

      $(document.createElement('p')).addClass('explanation').attr('id', 'explanation').html('&nbsp;').appendTo('#frame');

      //questions holder
      $(document.createElement('ul')).attr('id', 'choice-block').appendTo('#frame').css({
        'padding-top': '20px'
      }) //add choices
      addChoices(quiz[0]['choices']);

      //add submit button
      $(document.createElement('div')).addClass('choice-box').attr('id', 'submitbutton').text('NEXT QUESTION').css({

      }).appendTo('#frame');

      setupButtons();
      $('#submitbutton').hide();
      $('#form1').hide();
    }
  }

  init();
});
```

```css
header {
   background: #005596;
   color: #ffffff;
   padding: 20px;
   overflow: auto;
   font-size: 21pt;
   margin-bottom: 40px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
 }

 .correct {
   color: #6C0;
   font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-size: 26pt;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 30px 0 10px 30px;
 }

 .wrong {
   color: #ff0000;
   font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-size: 26pt;
   text-align: left;
   padding: 30px 0 10px 30px;
 }

 ol,
 ul {
   list-style: none;
   list-style-position: inside;
 }

 p.pager {
   margin: 5px 0 5px;
   font-weight: 500;
   font-size: 2em;
   line-height: 2em;
   color: #999;
 }

 #choice-block {
   display: block;
   list-style: none;
   margin: -20px 15px 0 -15px;
   padding: 0;
 }

 #submitbutton {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: none;
   appearance: none;
   background: #005596;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 12px;
   font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14pt;
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 20px;
 }

 #submitbutton:hover {
   background-color: #f1cb00;
   text-decoration: none;
   -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: 0.3s;
   -ms-transition: 0.3s;
   -o-transition: 0.3s;
   transition: 0.3s;
 }

 #Submit {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   border: none;
   appearance: none;
   background: #005596;
   display: inline-block;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 20px;
   font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14pt;
   color: #FFF;
   font-weight: bold;
   margin-top: 20px;
 }

 #Submit:hover {
   background-color: #f1cb00;
   text-decoration: none;
   -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
   -moz-transition: 0.3s;
   -ms-transition: 0.3s;
   -o-transition: 0.3s;
   transition: 0.3s;
 }

 .choice-box {
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
   margin: 8px auto;
   color: #005596;
   font-weight: 300;
   font-size: 20px;
   padding: 20px;
   cursor: pointer;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   -moz-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   background: #e1e1e1;
 }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
   .correct {
     padding: 20px 0 0 0;
   }
   .wrong {
     padding: 20px 0 0 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="frame" role="content">
```

Comment: @user3067421 I've updated the answer. I hope this helps.

Comment: Just curious, for (relatively) "simple" applications, why'd you recommend using a framework. (Like using Laravel for a 1 page email subscribe form). It seems like overkill

Comment: @KerwinSneijders Of course, it depends on your needs, and the main question is to spend less time getting the best result, because almost every application solves some business problems. For me, there is no difference in using a framework or using pure JS (or jQuery) if the application is written most concisely and reliably. My idea is simple: the simpler the application logic, the more reliable it is. And there are so many frameworks that can help us easily implement things.

Comment: @KerwinSneijders As for this particular application, I can see too much messy code where an unexpected problem may appear, because this code is difficult to read, support and test. Once again: there is no need to use frameworks everywhere, and I advised to learn one of the frameworks to show that this application can be implemented in another way. Perhaps user3067421 will learn new architectural patterns (for example, MVC) or practices that will allow him to continue writing SPA using jQuery, but a little better organized.

Comment: @KerwinSneijders As for your question (`using Laravel for a 1 page email subscribe form`) - it depends on logic, but if this is really a simple form, than you don't need a framework. Perhaps you don't need JS also, just pure HTML. I cannot see any problem in an app without frameworks, if the code is easy to read, support, scale and test.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've not used a framework for JS yet, so this is a good start!

Comment: @Max Martynov Thank you for all your help and advice! This works great now! I did look at the other links provided, great resources, but for now due to time restraints, I will continue with this solution. Thank you again!! BTW ... do you know Coldfusion? I have another issue I am trying to work through for a secure login that is specific to a user_ID, like creating an online account, where you can only see your own data and no one else's.

Comment: @user3067421 I apologize, but I have never worked with Coldfusion. Try to create a new question

Comment: @user3067421 don't forget to mark this answer if it really helped you, or let me know if there are points that I can clarify for you